# Square of a matrix difference is a scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two $2\times 2$ matrices $A,B$, let $C=AB-BA$.
Show that $C^2$ is a scalar matrix (i.e. $C=\lambda I$).

Is there a simple way to do this? I feel like I am just missing a manipulation trick.

I am working on using the fact that any matrix is unitarily similar to some matrix with all diagonal entries the same, but have not had much luck. Do you have any thoughts on the direction I should take this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that really matters here is that for $2\times2$ matrices, the $(1,1)$ element and the $(2,2)$ element of $AB-BA$ are equal and opposite.  So, check this, then to avoid messy algebra just write
$$AB-BA=\pmatrix{p&q\cr r&-p\cr}$$
and square it.

**Addendum**.  Here is a counterexample for $n>2$, as requested by @user901823.

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices: $A$ has first row all $1$s, otherwise $0$, while $B$ has first column all $1$s, otherwise $0$.  Then
$$C=AB-BA=\pmatrix{n-1&-1&-1&\cdots\cr -1&-1&-1&\cdots\cr -1&-1&-1&\cdots\cr
  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\cr}$$
and the $(2,3)$ entry of $C^2$ is
$$\pmatrix{-1&-1&-1&\cdots\cr}\pmatrix{-1\cr-1\cr-1\cr\vdots\cr}=n\ne0\ .$$

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is best. I was hoping for a "cool" way to answer the question because my professor had indicated that it could be done by using unitary matrices. But brute force may be the best method.

Comment: To add on to this, if $A = \left(\begin{array}{rr} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ and $B = \left(\begin{array}{rr} w & x \\ y & z\end{array}\right)$, then $p = by-cx$, $q = (a-d)x+b(z-w)$ and $r = (a-d)y+c(w-z)$.

Comment: What's a counterexample for general commutators?

Comment: @user901823, see extended answer ;-)